# Anaconda version with Python 3.5

Tags: python, anaconda

I want to install tensorflow with python 3.5 using anaconda but I don't know which anaconda version has python 3.5. When I go to anaconda download page am presented with Anaconda 4.3.1 which has either version 3.6 or 2.7 of python

Comment: You are presented with???

Comment: So which one was the correct solution?! Please mark it.

Comment: `wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh`

Comment: Install the latest verison of Anaconda (with whatever Python version), then *within* the conda environment, install the desired Python version. That's the whole point of conda - you can have environments with different versions.

Comment: @GabrielFair If you change `Anaconda2` to `Anaconda3` in your URL, then it will download Anaconda with Python 3.5.2

Comment: The problem with creating a new environment just to get a specific python version is that you won't be able to use any of the base packages from that envrionment. If you only need python 3.5, it makes more sense to install the precise Anaconda version which comes with 3.5 and the base environment built for 3.5 (@alchemy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48142111/5486210) provides helpful info to find it).

Answer (score 44):

You can install any current version of Anaconda.  You can then make a conda environment with your particular needs from [the documentation](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html)

```
conda create -n tensorflowproject python=3.5 tensorflow ipython
```

This command has a specific version for python and when this tensorflowproject environment gets updated it will upgrade to Python 3.5999999999 but never go to 3.6 .  Then you switch to your environment using either

```
source activate tensorflowproject
```

for linux/mac or

```
activate tensorflowproject
```

on windows

Comment: Hi, your solution looks interesting, but I get: PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current win-64 channels:
  - tensorflow ;;; any ideas?

Comment: You can do a search on anaconda.org ( https://anaconda.org/search?q=tensorflow ) you will see that tensorflow is handled for win-64 under the conda-forge repo.  Here is info about how to allow downloading of conda-forge packages https://conda-forge.github.io/#about

Comment: What is tensorflowproject exactly? Is that a folder name or a solution name of the project? What is it? Thanks.

Comment: "tensorflowproject" is a name I gave to this group of packages.  The environment has to have a name that is distinct from other environments.  After the project is created with the project name like "tensorflowproject" or "nicksproject" it can be used with other commands to effect that environment like "activate tensorflowproject".  I just edited the post to point to the documentation.  side note: I usually make my environment names based on the project that I'm building.

Comment: Thanks! conda environments seem really useful!

Comment: It works. Need caution to install 64bit Anaconda on Windows.

Comment: This also works: `conda create -n tensorflow_env tensorflow` and it defaults to a workable python version per [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/tensorflow-in-anaconda/)

Comment: @j2abro Those instructions will download the latest tensorflow library version and the latest python version that works with it.  Which is great because it's usually what we want!  But not what the question was asking.  Sammy was asking for a specific version of Python with the latest version of Tensorflow that went with it.

Comment: If you use oh-my-zsh in terminal, you have to use 'source activate **' to activate the env.

Answer (score 39):

Per [this announcement](https://www.scivision.co/switch-anaconda-python-36/), Anaconda upgraded to Python 3.6 starting with version 4.3, so... you probably want the 4.2.0 package from the [installer archive](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/index.html).

Comment: Why that installer archive link is that hard to find from the official website? (I am not being ironic)

Comment: They probably want to push users to the newest version (understandably). But yeah, it was annoying to find.

Answer (score 16):

According to the [official docu](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/faq#how-do-i-get-the-latest-anaconda-with-python-3-5) it's recommended to downgrade the whole Python environment:

```
conda install python=3.5
```

Comment: This does not work, because after installing you have plenty of dependencies and they deny you to downgrade. So you have to remove first the whole dependencies which is a mess

Answer (score 12):

Anacoda3-4.2.0 Uses python 3.5 
You can find the same in the link given below :
https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.2.0-Windows-x86_64.exe

I faced the same problem and found the correct version by checking the available Anaconda 4.2.0 distributions in installer archive [here](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/index.html)

Comment: It seems 4.2.0 is with python 2.7?

Comment: If the file name says Anaconda3 then its python 3.x and if it is Anaconda2 then its 2.x. Look carefully, hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

command install:

- python3.5: `conda install python=3.5`
- python3.6: `conda install python=3.6`

download the most recent Anaconda installer:

- python3.5: `Anaconda 4.2.0`
- python3.6: `Anaconda 5.2.0`

reference from anaconda doc:

- [How do I get Anaconda with Python 3.5 or 3.6?](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/#getting-anaconda)

Answer (score 2):

To highlight a few points:

The docs recommend using an install environment:
https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/download.html#choosing-a-version-of-anaconda-or-miniconda

The version archive is here:
https://repo.continuum.io/archive/

The version history is here:
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/release-notes

"`Anaconda3` then its python 3.x and if it is `Anaconda2` then its 2.x" - +1 papbiceps

The version archive is sorted newest at the top, but `Anaconda2` **ABOVE** `Anaconda3`.

Comment: Thanks for version archive link !

Answer (score -2):

It is very simple, first, you need to be inside the virtualenv you created, then to install a specific version of python say 3.5, use Anaconda, `conda install python=3.5`

In general you can do this for any python package you want

conda install **package_name=package_version**