# Python on anaconda cannot find azure.mgmt.datafactory

Tags: python, azure, anaconda, azure-data-factory

I am trying to run this tutorial

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-python

but I fail to install the packages. I tried several installations but I keep getting the error `No module named 'azure.mgmt.datafactory'` when trying to run `from azure.mgmt.datafactory import DataFactoryManagementClient`.

I am using anaconda and windows 10.

I tried running the recommended anaconda packages https://anaconda.org/anaconda/azure and https://anaconda.org/clinicalgraphics/azure-mgmt-resource under a python 3.5 environment and I also tried to manually install everything from github (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python) using

```
git clone git://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python.git 
cd azure-sdk-for-python 
python setup.py install
```

In both the normal (Python 3.6) and the new (Python 3.5, using  [Anaconda version with Python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978349/anaconda-version-with-python-3-5?noredirect=1&lq=1)) environment. None of this worked.

What am I missing?

(Note that `from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient` worked fine with the anaconda installation)

**EDIT**

After the first response, I ran the following commands from the powershell

```
 pip install azure-mgmt-resource
 pip install azure-mgmt-datafactory
 pip install azure-mgmt
```

which resulted in `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.mgmt'`

Uninstalling the three packages and installing azure-mgmt as a first one did not solve the issue either. However, I don't know how to uninstall the manually installed package from `python setup.py install`, which still might be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried pip install in powershell/cmd?

```
pip install azure-mgmt-datafactory
```

Update (Jan's answer):

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
pip uninstall -r requirements.txt
python -m pip install azure-common
python -m pip install azure-mgmt
python -m pip install azure-mgmt-datafactory (this might not be needed as it comes with azure-mgmt)
```

Comment: I seem to remember a time when pip did not work in anaconda. The installation worked, but now it says `No module named 'azure.mgmt'` - I'll try to uninstall everything and give it another shot.

Comment: Sorry, uninstalling everything (as good as possible) and running the pip commands (also `pip install azure-mgmt-resource`) under powershell resultet in the same error. No module named `azure.mgmt`

Comment: seems like a different problem, do you have multiple python interpreters installed? check this out:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680081/importerror-after-successful-pip-installation you may want to python -m pip install <library-name> installs it in the default interpreter run this which -a python and see how many you have, the first one should be the one that runs from powershell.

Comment: just to be on the same page, you pip uninstalled both azure-mgmt-datafactory and azure-mgmt and did pip install azure-mgmt again? just do a pip install azure-mgmt as recommended https://pypi.python.org/pypi/azure-mgmt and not azure-mgmt-resource

Comment: OK, I got `azure.mgmt.datafacory` briefly to work, but then `azure.common.credentials` could not be found any more. Now, after uninstalling and reinstalling `azure.mgmt.datafactory`, `azure.common.credentials` returned but now the datafactory is missing again.

Comment: Hmm interesting, where are you running your python code? Your imports, etc. Which editor are you using? Pycharm, spyder?

Comment: I run my code in iPython, which might be an outdated way of working but does the job for me.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is how I got the required azure libraries to work (thx to Saul Cruy, who gave me the idea)

Using this post [What is the easiest way to remove all packages installed by pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248073/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-all-packages-installed-by-pip?noredirect=1&lq=), I created a requirements file in PowerShell

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

In this file, I manually kept only the entries with azure.
Then, I deleted all packages in the file

```
pip uninstall -r requirements.txt
```

The steps above were repeated twice, as upon first delete, some azure packages survived.

Then, I ran (all in PowerShell, in that order)

```
python -m pip install azure-common
python -m pip install azure-mgmt
python -m pip install azure-mgmt-datafactory
```

The reason might(!) be that installing packages in the anaconda console using the `conda` commands causes confusion in the dependencies (I tried a similar approach in a conda environment as it seemed like a good idea to seperate the azure packages from the other ones, but without success).