# How to install the specific version of Python with Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda

I want to install Anaconda with Python Version 3.6.5. If I install Anaconda3-5.2.0, It install Python 3.5.1.  Where to download the Anaconda with Python 3.6.5.  The Big Data Scripts work only with Anaconda Python 3.6.5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anaconda version with Python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42978349/4518341) (I know it's a different version number, but the methods should be the same)

Comment: Specifically what errors are you getting when running these "big data scripts" with Python 3.5?

Answer (score 13):

## Anaconda Downloads

The Anaconda distribution with Python 3.6.5 was **version 5.2.0**.<sup>**1**</sup> You can download this from [the Anaconda distribution archive](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/). If you do install from this, then make sure to update Conda immediately after installation:

```
conda update conda
```

However, **I strongly recommend the following alternate solution** as better practice.

## Miniconda + Anaconda environment

#### Reasoning

What is installed in the **base** environment is relatively fixed once installed. Ultimately, you don't want to mess with your **base** environment, so best practice is to have the latest version there. Fortunately, you don't have to install a full Anaconda distribution, but rather can use a lightweight Miniconda (or Miniforge) distribution and create a secondary environment for the purpose of having an Anaconda Python 3.6.5 distribution. In the long run this will give you better stability.

#### Steps

1. Download and install [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) or a [Miniforge variant](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#miniforge). Once that is working...
2. Create your Anaconda env:

   ```
    conda create --name my_env -c anaconda python=3.6.5 anaconda=5.2.0
   ```
3. Use your new isolated env:

   ```
    conda activate my_env
   ```

---

<sub>**[1]** I determined this by running `conda create -n foo --dry-run -c anaconda python=3.6.5 anaconda` and then examining the version of the `anaconda` package that Conda ended up with in the solve.</sub>

Answer (score 10):

Also try

```
conda install python=3.6.5
```

but you may encounter some incompatibility issues with other packages.

Alternatively, you may want to try creating a new environment. From the anaconda prompt, create a custom environment and specify the repository channel to find the version

```
conda create --name py365 python=3.6.5 --channel conda-forge
```

Activate the new environment

```
conda activate py365
```

However, the activation will not be permanent, and you will need to activate each time you start the anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 1):

In your anaconda prompt, you can manually update your python to the latest version with :

```
conda update python
```

In case you are not familiar with it, anaconda prompt is installed to your computer when you install anaconda.  Just make a search for it on your computer.

You can refer to this post : [How do I upgrade to Python 3.6 with conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535881/how-do-i-upgrade-to-python-3-6-with-conda)