# conda create environment with specific build (and version) of *anaconda*

Tags: anaconda, conda

How can I create a new environment with a specific build and version of anaconda?
Want to install a specific (in my case the latest) python 3.5, which should be based [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978349/anaconda-version-with-python-3-5)
Tried e.g.

```
conda create -n py35 anaconda==4.2
```

and all variations...

Comment: `conda create -n py35 anaconda=5.2` would work. `anaconda=4.2` does not seem to be available in the channels (anymore?).

Comment: @cel why would one want a specific anaconda version in a conda environment??

Comment: @droptop I think there are confusions with the term `anaconda`. `anaconda can refer to (a) the installer for a scientific software distribution provided by AnacondaInc. or (b) a meta-package that defines all the packages that are shipped in the base environment of the anaconda installer. This question refers to (b). Installing a specific version of anaconda gives you a specific set of packages that you e.g. may want to use to reproduce a scientific result.

Comment: @cel the question clearly states its objective `Want to install latest python3.5`. The latest `python 3.5` version is not necessarily referred to by one of the anaconda versions. So it's more helpful to install the package separately rather than hope a specific conda version has it

Comment: @cel Thanx. that was the problem. Though, I had to also add the build not to get the latest python :)

Comment: as cel writes, this refers to (b) As he mentions this is quite useful bc it sets the version of most packages to a well known, tested and easily reproducible, well behaving set that is acceptable to the solver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as  @cel suggested... So I had to first find the latest available anaconda version using

```
conda search -f anaconda
```

Ignoring nightly builds and so on, (which you may not want to :) )
I ended up deciding to use anaconda 5.2.0, whish still has py3.5 and so did:

```
conda create -n py35 anaconda==5.2.0=py35_3
```

Note I had to **specify the build** here.

I suppose future users will first to check what is the latest available anaconda that fits them using search as well...

top part of my results:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Step-1 : Install latest version of anaconda

Step-2 : conda create --name envname python=3.5

Step-3 : Use "conda activate envname" or simple "activate venv" (depending upon version of anaconda) to activate the virtual environment created

You can also see the official docs here.
You can also follow steps given at https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html#managing-python

Comment: Step 1 could mess up around 10 other environments in my case... Also, I did not want to just install python 3.5, but also all the anaconda packages... For `conda create --name py35 python=3.5 anaconda` my solver hangs and had to kill it after 3 hours....